# Macos - zsh - Unknown and undeletable file: <!--

Tags: macos, command-line, bash, zsh

I have recently noticed a file that I have not intentionally created, appearing in directories with files I have intentionally created:

```
<!--
```

The file contents change depending on location, but is generally text from another file in the same directory.

e.g.

```
.../Foo/
        <!--
        foo.js
```

in `Code/Foo/`, there exist files`<!--` and `foo.txt`, where `cat <!--` === `cat foo.txt`

- This file `<!--` cannot be removed with `rm -rf` nor with `sudo rm -rf`
- Its `time of creation` is the same as `foo.txt`
- Changes to `foo.txt` are not seen in `<!--`
- In `git` directories, git wants to commit `<!--` (as one might expect)
- `ls -lash` reveals file size of `<!--` at creation  === file size of `foo.txt` before changes

Search engine results have been fruitless, I believe because the file is composed of symbols (or my search-foo is poor).

**What might be generating this file? How might I rid myself of this (likely self-inflicted) curse?**

*`Env:`
MBP 2017
`MacOs; Mojave; v10.14.6` / `zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0)`*

Comment: `cannot be removed` – What exact command(s) do you invoke to try to remove it? What is the error? When you're running `cat <!--`, is the command literally `cat <!--`? I'm asking because `<` and `!` are special for the shell. The desired command is `cat '<!--'`, I guess.

Comment: The exact command is a tab-completed, escaped `<!--`; so `cat \<\!--`. There is no error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Files with weird names can be manipulated by e.g. `./'<--'` (the `./` to avoid any issues with  names confused with switches, the single quotes so any characters the shell processes specially lose their meaning).

Comment: Ah of course! This definitely _deletes_ the file

Answer (score 0):

I found this, in reference to your foo.js file: https://github.com/uupaa/Foo.js/wiki/Foo

Also this: https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/5a99e069aca0a35d51e66f2d7fde5b80

Apparently, both are files linked to a webmodule of some sort, probably imported by a browser extension.

They don't seem malignant.

Comment: Thanks- I should state that the directory `Foo` and the file(s) `foo.js`/`foo.txt` are representations, rather than the exact filetype. The filetype of the siblings of `<!--` does not appear to have any consistency or show correlation.